# Dear friends, how can I solve this problem? Please help me answer this question, thank you very much

Tags: solana-cli

spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb initialize-metadata EXMuzR**********AWKqtmX6oVgN Test Token TTKN https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUwBmxm9F4qcK6RKtaLeJYGcFzE3NxomqqDA4FjKiNG43?filename=metadata.json
error: Found argument 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUwBmxm9F4qcK6RKtaLeJYGcFzE3NxomqqDA4FjKiNG43?filename=metadata.json' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
spl-token initialize-metadata [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] <TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS> <TOKEN_NAME> <TOKEN_SYMBOL> <TOKEN_URI>

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simply, the "name" argument of "Test Token" has a space in it, but it wasn't quoted, so the CLI is not correctly parsing your command.

Be sure to quote any arguments that have a space in them, so try running:

```
spl-token initialize-metadata EXMuzR**********AWKqtmX6oVgN "Test Token" TTKN https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUwBmxm9F4qcK6RKtaLeJYGcFzE3NxomqqDA4FjKiNG43?filename=metadata.json
```